# SQL Drop down to include hidden parameters

Tags: sql, drop-down-menu, dropdownlistfor, tlist, powerschool

the code listed below currently populates the drop down list like

All Sports

Sports - Baseball

Sports - Bowling

Sports - Basketball

which is really

Logtypid=3935  -  subtypeid=x

I am in need for the subtype id to pull 2 additional subtypes, that do not hold a logtypeid of 3935, but the issue is that those subtypes have a logtypeid of 626. I only need the students that have a logtypeid of 3935 though. Currently.. the way I have it written:

```
SELECT DISTINCT log.logtypeid, 
CASE WHEN log.subtype is null THEN ' ' ELSE log.subtype END subID, 
CASE WHEN ','||'~[gpv:lt]'||',' LIKE '%,' || log.subtype || '.' || CASE WHEN log.subtype is null THEN ' ' ELSE log.subtype END || ',%' THEN 'selected' ELSE '' END isselected,
lt.Name logtype, 
CASE WHEN to_char(st.ValueT) is null THEN ' - NONE' ELSE ' - ' || to_char(st.ValueT) END subtype
FROM log
INNER JOIN gen lt ON log.logtypeid = lt.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN gen st ON st.Name = to_char(lt.ID)
AND st.value = log.subtype
AND st.Cat = 'subtype'
WHERE lt.Cat = 'logtype'
AND  logtypeid = '3935'
AND to_char(log.schoolid) like CASE WHEN ~(curschoolid) = 0 THEN '%' ELSE to_char(~(curschoolid)) END
ORDER BY subtype
              ;]
```

I have tried everything and I am beginning to think that maybe in order to get the results needed, I may need to create a table for it. Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Data Example:

STUDENTID       LOGTYPEID       SUBTYPE
  6382             626             27
  6382             626             41
  6382             626             38
  6382             626             43
  6382             626             29
  6382            3935            109
  6382            3935            117
  6383             626             43
  6383             626             30
  6383             626             43
  6383             626             25
  6383             626             43
  6383             626             14
  6383            3935            117
  6400             626             38
  6401             626             28
  6401             626             36
  6401            3935            110
```

The code is populating select options, using tlist, for a drop down which is used to run a report. The select option names are from within the GEN table, which should explain the joins. Sports logs are 3935, and health logs are 626. We only wanna display sports logs in the drop down list. When Sports - Baseball is selected, and the report is run, the output should be only students who have logtype 3935 and subtype x(whichever subtype is baseball), but the output needs to also pull the same students logtypeid 626, specifically only subtype 29 and 43. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is tough without knowing how data is stored in the tables, the data itself and the output. But, here goes another stab in the dark:

To summarize: You want every logtype with id "3935", and the subtypes of this. Then you also want two subtypes from another logtype, with id "626".

Data example (in reality, you're getting data from two tables):

```
logtypeid    subtype    name
3935         100        Baseball
3935         101        Bowling
626          29         Fishing
626          43         Golfing
```

So far it's quite straight forward, but then there is a quite messy select-case that I'll just hope doesn't need changing.

How about:

```
WHERE lt.Cat = 'logtype'
AND (logtypeid = '3935' OR (logtypeid = '626' AND subtype IN ('29','43')))
```

Since I'm not sure how "lt.Cat" behaves, this might be needed:

```
WHERE ((lt.Cat = 'logtype' AND logtypeid = '3935') OR (lt.Cat = 'subtype' AND logtypeid = '626' AND subtype IN ('29','43')))
```

I've tried re-engineering your DB in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) but I'm not doing it 100% correctly. Please add an example in sqlfiddle if you need more help with this, so I can test it with data.

Comment: unfortunately I need only the 3935 logtypeid listed which will have subtypes of 100-130.. but when a specific subtype is chosen from the drop down, I also need those student logtypeid 626, subtype id 29's and 43's.. if that makes sense.

Comment: I feel like it would need to be a CASE WHEN or CASE IF subtype IN (100-130), then also need logtypeid=626, subtype IN (29,43) for those studentids.

Comment: to give a visual explanation:  
Sports - Baseball (students who have logtypeid=3935, and subtype=101) + plus pull those same student logtypeid 626, subtype IN ('29','43')

Comment: your suggestion Mackan would only include logtypeid 626 into the drop down menu. I only need logtypeid 3935 to be listed.

Comment: Ok, i'll have another look at this in a bit, and see if I can understand your request and requirements

Comment: First time using SQL Fiddle, I created the schema but it has no data. Working on it now so you have something to work with. Thanks again